# MySQL logs are not working due to permissions

Tags: centos, logs, mysql, mariadb

I am having a issue regarding permissions in MariaDB (MySQL) log files. I had setup logs files to be on `/var/log/mysql` but any time I restart the MariaDB server I can see the following messages logged in `/var/log/mysql/mysql_error.log`:

```
151104 20:54:53 [ERROR] mysqld: File '/var/log/mysql/mysql_slow.log' not found (Errcode: 13)
151104 20:54:53 [ERROR] Could not use /var/log/mysql/mysql_slow.log for logging (error 13). Turning logging off for the whole duration of the MySQL server process. To turn it on again: fix the cause, shutdown the MySQL server and restart it.
151104 20:54:53 [ERROR] mysqld: File '/var/log/mysql/mysql_query.log' not found (Errcode: 13)
151104 20:54:53 [ERROR] Could not use /var/log/mysql/mysql_query.log for logging (error 13). Turning logging off for the whole duration of the MySQL server process. To turn it on again: fix the cause, shutdown the MySQL server and restart it.
```

I have tried setting up permissions on `/var/log/mysql` recursive (-R) as `mysql:root`, `mysql:mysql` and `root:root` none of them works and I got the same messages all the time. I did check the current permissions on `/var/log/mysql` and read as:

```
# ls -l mysql/
total 40
-rw-r--r-- 1 mysql root 33088 Nov  4 21:04 mysql_error.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 mysql root     0 Aug  2 16:58 mysql_query.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 mysql root     0 Aug  2 16:58 mysql_slow.log
```

I am using *mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.46-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1*

What is wrong here? Which are the right permissions on this case?

**Update**

Here are the permissions for `/var/log` and `/var/log/mysql`:

```
# ls -lhd /var/log/
drwx------ 12 root root 4.0K Nov  4 20:52 /var/log/
# ls -lhd /var/log/mysql
drwxr-xr-x 2 mysql root 4.0K Nov  4 20:52 /var/log/mysql
```

Comment: Few things to check **(A)** /var/log/ & /var/log/mysql/ must have **read&execute permissions** for all users **(B)** when mysql is running, there will be two processes, 1 running as root and 1 running as some other user (most common user is "mysql") so get the **ps output** and find **which user** is running the mysql process.

Comment: @Prem I have updated the answer - take a look - though I am not following you on your statement here *must have read&execute permissions for all users* can you explain that? Is secure to change those permissions or it can affect any other process logging? And I look the user with `ps -ax` and it's `mysql` so it's right

Comment: From your update, service is running as correct mysql user , so (B) is resolved. I see that (A) is the problem : Currently, mysql user can not look into /var/log/ so "chmod 755 /var/log/" will solve your problem. Default for /var/log/ is rwxr-xr-x & it is only for writing log files, so it is not a security risk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have to give the mysql user read and execute permissions to `/var/log` before it can access `/var/log/mysql`. I just tested this on RHEL7.1 and confirmed the same issue.

This is precisely as @prem suggested in the comments.